# Deleting an alarm with alarmManager.cancel after alertdialog

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I've got a button in a list item to delete the item. When there is an alarm linked to the item I want to delete the alarm too.
To delete the item I show an alert dialog, with the delete function in the positive button:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    DeleteList del = new DeleteList();
                    del.execute(listId);
                }
            });
```

But I need to delete the alarm too, and the problem is the alarm is set in another activity. I have the unique id for the PendingIntent, but I can't create the PendingIntent because I'm in a static context.

If I do:

```
AddListActivityFragment.deleteAlarmS(alarmId);
```

I get Non-static method cannot be referenced from static context.

If I do:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(AddListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddListActivity.this, Integer.parseInt(alarmId), resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if(deleteIntent != null) {
               AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) AddListActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(deleteIntent);
        deleteIntent.cancel();
    }
```

I get "AddListActivity is not an enclosing class".

How can I solve this? How can I cancel the alarm? Do I sent some broadcast with the id that is received by AddListActivity?

Thanks

Thanks to qbix, I managed to make the method in AddListActivityFragment static. But it still doesn't cancel the alarm.

How the alarm is set in AddListActivityFragment:

```
 private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, long delay, int alarmId) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationPublisher.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, alarmId);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, alarmId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Log.v("alarm id", "alarmid = " + alarmId);
    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}

private Notification getNotification(String content, String subText, int alarmId) {
    Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    long[] vib = new long[]{1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L};
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    alarmId,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setContentTitle("To do!");
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSubText(subText);
    builder.setSound(uri);
    builder.setVibrate(vib);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    return builder.build();
}
```

alarm set with:

```
scheduleNotification(getNotification(title, subText, alarmId), delay, alarmId);
```

How I try to cancel the alarm:

```
 public static void deleteAlarm(String alarmId){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "delete alarm active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v("alarm id delete", "alarmid = " + alarmId);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationPublisher.class);
    PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, Integer.parseInt(alarmId), resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if(deleteIntent != null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Alarm deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(deleteIntent);
        deleteIntent.cancel();
    }
}
```

The "delete alarm active" Toast shows up, and the alarmId is the right one. But the Toast "alarm deleted" doesn't show and the alarm still goes off. Isn't the PendingIntent the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AddListActivity`, declare a private static member of type `Context`:

```
private static Context mContext;
```

In the `onCreate()` method of `AddListActivity`, initialize it:

```
mContext = this;
```

In the code block to build the `PendingIntent` and cancel the alarm, replace `AddListActivity.this` with `mContext`.

Comment: Thank you, this made it possible to make the method in AddListActivity static. But it still doesn't delete the alarm. I'll post the code in an edit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
Apparently the PendingIntent needs the same flag, so when I changed it to PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT in the deleteAlarm method it worked.
Thanks for the help.